# Como ordenar o grid layout por coluna? (CSS)

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

Estou tentando usar um gridlayout para organizar os  `<li>` da minha lista em 4 colunas, porém ao fazer isso os itens ficam ordenados por linha. Ex.:
[item 1] [item 2] [item 3] [item 4]
[item 5] [item 6] [item 7] [item 8]

Queria saber o que fazer para que essas li fiquem ordenadas por coluna, da seguinte forma:
[item 1] [item 3] [item 5] [item 7]
[item 2] [item 4] [item 6] [item 8]

**Lembrando que a quantidade de `<li>` é aleatória.**

Answer (score -2):

Essa seria a melhor forma de colocar em 4 colunas ou mais e 2 linhas, nessa ordem que  você quer.

```
ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).